Using transformer package in PySpark gives module not found error
I am using a pretrained huggingface model inside a SparkNLP pipeline:
class T5_EP(Wikify):
    """This pipeline generates elevator pitch for a given paper abstract using T5 model"""
    def __init__(self, feature_col, index_col, result_col):
        super().__init__(feature_col, index_col, result_col)
        self.model_name = const.DEFAULT_T5_EP_MODEL
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(self.model_name)
        self.model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(self.model_name)
        
        self.task = "summarize:"
        self.ep = "elevator pitch"
        self.feature_col = feature_col
        self.index_col = index_col
        self.result_col = result_col
        self.max_output = const.ELEVATOR_PITCH_MAX_OUTPUT


    def gen_elevator_pitch(self, spark_sess, data):
        """Function to generate an elevator pitch for a given paper abstract"""
        def summarizer(text):
            inputs = self.tokenizer.encode("summarize: " + text, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True)
            outputs = self.model.generate(inputs, max_length=const.ELEVATOR_PITCH_MAX_OUTPUT, num_beams=4, early_stopping=True)
            return self.tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

        summarize_udf = udf(summarizer, StringType())
        result = data.withColumn(self.result_col, summarize_udf(data[self.feature_col]))

        result = self.post_process(result)
        results_df.show(truncate=False)
        return result
    
    def post_process(self, result):
        # Implement any post-processing steps if needed
        return result

This whole code is inside the file x.py; however, when I run the pipeline, it keeps throwing "no module named x" error. I suspect its a problem of PySpark trying to serialize transformer functions, is there anyway to solve it?
My attempt is based on: https://towardsdatascience.com/large-models-meet-big-data-spark-and-llms-in-harmony-5e2976b69b62
